# Why in Editor type script it's never get to the break point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetPrefabs : Editor
{
    public GameObject[] prefabs;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        prefabs = (GameObject[])Resources.LoadAll("Assets/Test/Animations/");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        prefabs = (GameObject[])Resources.LoadAll("Assets/Test/Animations/");
    }
}
```

First I tried to put the script inside Assets/Test/Editor but it didn't work then I moved the script to Assets/Editor but it's not working either it's never get to the break point I put on the line in the Update or in the Start.

Comment: Could be I need to enable something in the editor settings ? I'm using the final version 2018.3.0f2 personal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetPrefabs derives from Editor. The Start() and Update() are MonoBehaviour methods (i.e. Unity looks for them if you derive from MonoBehaviour). You should look at Unity docs for the Editor class and pick appropriate methods from its list - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html

Comment: But how can I make it to execute automatic in the editor ? Not working.  Something like [ExecuteInEditMode] with MonoBehaviour so with Editor. I want it to be execute once I'm in the editor.

Comment: My main goal is to detect with an event changes in the Assets for example in Assets/Test if a new gameobject created there or dragged to there in editor mode without running the game.

Comment: If I understand correctly next may help you - [Creating Basic Editor Tools](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/creating-basic-editor-tools?playlist=17117)